# File upload - Bad request (400)

Tags: python, django

When I try to upload file via FileField of my model using Django administration I get following response from Django development server:

```
<h1>Bad Request (400)</h1>
```

The only output in console is:

```
[21/Jul/2013 17:55:23] "POST /admin/core/post/add/ HTTP/1.1" 400 26
```

I have tried to find an error log, but after reading few answers here I think there is nothing like that because Django usually prints debug info directly to browser window when `Debug=True` (my case).

How can I debug this problem further?

Comment: You should post the code that uploads the image. And I'm hoping you're using the correct `enctype`.

Comment: @DanielFigueroa The point of the question was to know how to debug these kind of things not just to solve the error 400.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my case it was a leading '/' character in models.py.

Changed `/products/` to `products/` in:

`product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')`

Comment: I think this was my problem too. I forgot to submit an answer here after solving the problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

Please check your upload location. I've also had 400 and in my case it was a permission issue.

> ERROR 2013-12-15 19:23:37,044 base 22938 140546689459968 Attempted access to '/uploads/nook.jpg' denied.

Configuring logging as shown here helped me: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Answer (score 2):

That true , it's sometime hard to find an error log in django but i discover another way to get an error log related to django.

install the django-db-log packages and configure the settings.py
    pip install django-db-log --upgrade or easy-install django-db-log

```
DBLOG_CATCH_404_ERRORS = True # enable the catching
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=('djangodblog.DBLogMiddleware',)
INSTALL_APPS =('djangodblog',)
$ ./manage.py syncdb
Creating table djangodblog_error
Installing index for djangodblog.ErrorBatch model
..........
...........
```

your django project will now log all of its exceptions to the table djangodblog_error. all we need now is an exception in the views or template for the application to catch the errors.

read this link in case of issue : https://github.com/dcramer/django-db-log